# Integrating $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^3}dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I have seen ways to evaluate this integral using the upper and lower incomplete gamma functions. I want to know if there are ways to calculate this integral using change of variables or tricks similar to the evaluation of 
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx $$ using double integrals.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, let $$f(s)=\int_0^\infty \exp(-x^s)dx$$ for any $s\in\Bbb C$ with $\lim_{x\to0}x^s=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^s=\infty$. Use the substitution $x=t^{1/s}$ so that $dx=\frac{1}{s}t^{1/s-1}dt$. This gives $$f(s)=\frac{1}{s}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{1/s-1}e^{-t}dt .$$ This is evaluable explicitly in terms of the Gamma function, namely $$f(s)=\frac{1}{s} \Gamma(\tfrac{1}{s})=\Gamma(1+\tfrac{1}{s}).$$

Answer (score 5):

There isn't any better form for this integral than

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^3}\ dx = \Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)$$

You can find this rather simply by substitution, giving exactly the form of the gamma function. As far as it is known, I believe, there is no simpler way to write the values of the gamma function at third-integer arguments like there is for half-integers, giving the nice forms involving the square root of $\pi$ that you are thinking of.

More generally, we have the identity

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^\alpha}\ dx = \Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha}\right)$$

in the same way, for all real $\alpha > 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Substituting $y=x^3$, we get
$$\int _0^\infty e^{-x^3}dx=\frac13\int_0^\infty e^{-y}y^{\frac13-1}dy=\frac13\Gamma(\frac13)=\Gamma(\frac43),$$

where $\Gamma(s)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: +1 for showing your steps and providing a link. That Is often important in answering questions about special functions

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the change of variables $x=\sqrt[3]{t}$ then the integral is equal to $$\frac{1}{3}\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})$$

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the other answers, the integral can be expressed in terms of $\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)$. As no closed-form expression of this constant is known, this is a sure sign that you can't find an alternative resolution method.